# Largest and smallest real

Tags: floating-point, precision, sml

How do I find the largest possible *real* and the *real* most close to zero?

There are library values `Int.maxInt` and `Int.minInt`, but the `Real` library doesn't seem to contain similar constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this http://sml-family.org/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.maxFinite:VAL

+- maxFinite should be your answer, right?

Comment: Sweet. This was another case of Moscow ML's standard library being non-standard, it seems.